# I want to develop a facebook app which will send users a Specific voucher code after they like my Facebook Page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, wordpress, facebook-like

I wants to create a facebook application which will send users a Specific voucher code after they like my facebook page.

After getting this code they can claim this voucher code on my wordpress website www.IndianApple.com

Please suggest me any code or application tutorials so that I can follow instruction and create my own application.
or suggest me any wordpress plugin which will do this trick.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

> Only incentivize a person to log into your app, enter a promotion on your app’s Page, or check-in at a place. Don’t incentivize other actions.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/policy/

You are not allowed to reward the user for liking your Page.